# VUETIFY Problem With Component Communication (Props / Events - Parent Child Communication)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

## Vuetify Component Communication Problem (Props / Events - Parent Child Communication)

Hi, I try to pass data between parent and child like this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPmg7ntQjzc

Regular HTML input works fine (just like in the tutorial).

But vuetify text field or text area don't work. 
(it seems fine at first. when I start type, it gives error)

What am I doing wrong?

// Child HTML

```
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="regular child"
      :value="valueRegularChild"
      @input="inputRegularChild"
      >
    <p>{{ regularInputValue }}</p> 


    <v-textarea
          type="text"
          placeholder="vuetify child"
          :value="valueVuetifyChild"
          @input="inputVuetifyChild"
      ></v-textarea>
    <p>{{ vuetifyInputValue }}</p>
```

// Child - methods

```
        inputVuetifyChild($event) {
            this.vuetifyInputValue = $event.target.value;
            this.$emit('msgVuetify', this.vuetifyInputValue);
        },
        inputRegularChild($event) {
            this.regularInputValue = $event.target.value;
            this.$emit('msgRegular', this.regularInputValue);
        },
```

// parent HTML

```
<child-component
        :valueVuetifyChild="insideParentVuetify"
        :valueRegularChild="insideParentRegular"
        @msgVuetify="insideParentVuetify = $event"
        @msgRegular="insideParentRegular = $event"
>
<child-component>
```

everything same.

Regular works, Vuetify don't

consol log error says:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

thanks in advance

Comment: Quickly glanced, but try `:input-value="valueVuetifyChild"` instead of `:value` maybe? Or just `$event` instead of `$event.target.value`. Vuetify uses different props and events sometimes than native components.

Comment: Yeah, it's the $event.target that is undefined. Try `inputRegularChild($event) {console.log($event)}` and see what you can use in there.

Comment: @Traxo & @ Andrew1325 yes you are right. `$event` instead of `$event.target.value` works perfect. Thanks. 
It also work with select menu. 

however, `it don't work with checkbox or radios`. Can you suggest something for them also?

Answer (score -1):

I think `v-model` should work fine instead of `:value` but haven't had time to test ist yet.

// Child HTML

```
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="regular child"
      v-model="valueRegularChild"
      @input="inputRegularChild"
      >
    <p>{{ regularInputValue }}</p> 


    <v-textarea
          type="text"
          placeholder="vuetify child"
          v-model="valueVuetifyChild"
          @input="inputVuetifyChild"
      ></v-textarea>
    <p>{{ vuetifyInputValue }}</p>
```

// Child - methods

```
        inputVuetifyChild($event) {

            this.$emit('msgVuetify', this.vuetifyInputValue);
        },
        inputRegularChild($event) {

            this.$emit('msgRegular', this.regularInputValue);
        },
```

// parent HTML

```
<child-component
        :valueVuetifyChild="insideParentVuetify"
        :valueRegularChild="insideParentRegular"
        @msgVuetify="insideParentVuetify = $event"
        @msgRegular="insideParentRegular = $event"
>
<child-component>
```

Comment: I tried but not works. it gives error (not only vuetify text field but also input area)

error says: 

commons.app.js:12663 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "valueRegularChild"

Comment: ok sorry I did not see that it was a prop... i need to take a look at it again later..

Comment: @Iwolf it work with above example ($event instead of $event.target.value)

but it is not work with checkbox and radios. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Are you using checkboxes like `<input type="checkbox" />` or something from vuetify?

Comment: I use v-checkbox. I actually manage to pass single values seperately. But I couldn't combine them into single array. (in other words, I can get value in multiple seperate strings, rather than in single array). Of course I can do it in parent, but I try to find a way to do it child component